Can ObjectBox sync data specifcally for a given user? (particularly in Flutter)
In their FAQs (https://objectbox.io/faq/) they suggest this is not yet possible (under the "Would ObjectBox be a good fit in my case?" question). Is this definitely the case? If so, do we know if/when this will be added? I've seen elsewhere that this has been on their roadmap for a while but not sure about the current status or how to track it.

Not sure if SO is the right place for this kind of question, but this is actively worked on. If you get in touch with ObjectBox directly, there might be better info.
